# What is the Russian for a "coffee sleeve"?

Tags: перевод

I mean things like in that picture - used to grab hot coffee cups.
[image]

Comment: Если названия еще не придумали - почему бы не назвать это подстаканником?

Comment: Потому что подстаканник - это другая вещь? :) Плюс, это ведь называют как-то баристы в кофейнях всяких.

Comment: They never give it to us with a coffee cup here, in Novosibirsk. So the thing does not have any name in my city. The list of possible reasons: 1. We don't have a tradition to take out the coffee. 2. Sometimes we take out the hot coffee, if it's cold outside and we are going for a walk. I often see that if the weather is chilly but not wet, they take out the coffee from the coffee house nearby and go for a walk. The cup is useful to warm their hands. If it's not so cold outside, they just don't take the coffee, they have an ice-cream. This applies only to my area, in Moscow they can do things i

Answer (score 7):

There are two term that are sort of competing with each other so far - which if them will become de-facto standard.

One is "картонный подстаканник".
The other one is - "капхолдер". 
There's also such thing like literal translation - "манжет на стаканчик" or "манжет для стаканчика" but de-facto it is less used than first two terms.

Surprisingly, though the second term is direct borrowing from English, in English cupholder is slightly different thing.

Here's what Russian retailers sees as cupholders:

[image]

And here's what it actually means in English:
[image]

As a side note - this phenomenon is not that rare, it is called [pseudo-anglicism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-anglicism#Russian) and there's a bunch of other neat examples - check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srrTPMjRRsU) video for instance (apart from the author mocking pronunciation - it's actually norma that words are phonetically changing).

Comment: Are these really pseudo-anglicisms? (English-like terms that "native English speakers would not readily recognize or understand"). "Face control" and "safing" (from your Wikipedia link) would be pseudo-anglicisms. However a пазл (jigsaw puzzle) is a type of puzzle, although in English the term includes crossword puzzles and other mental challenges. And байкер == "biker": a motorcycle rider (note that a bicycle rider is a "cyclist"). Usually "master" would be used descriptively ("master craftsman", "master chef", "master of disguise") rather than as a standalone noun. All mostly recognizable.

Comment: @ghostarbeiter we can talk of degrees here - some terms like "face control" are pure Russian inventions, some just mean slightly different things in English, some are sort of parts of the full term (like jigsaw puzzle). I'm removing master since to be honest it is unfair example, indeed one can claim this cane to Russian not via English. Biker is incorrect, but puzzle - well, can be considerer pseudo-anglicism. Thank you actually for helping to improve the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The guy in the coffee shop I patronize calls it *манжета*.

Brief googling shows he's not the only one to do that.

Comment: The same I've heard in a local Starbucks.